# I'm confused about Scrapy Source Codes in shell.py

Tags: python, scrapy

I have been learning python for about one month, and I was reading scrapy source code during last week.
It's OK for me to understand modules like spiders or crawler. Until I found something interesting in 'shell.py', I was totally confused. Here is the codes.

```
def _request_deferred(request):
    """Wrap a request inside a Deferred.

    This function is harmful, do not use it until you know what you are doing.

    This returns a Deferred whose first pair of callbacks are the request
    callback and errback. The Deferred also triggers when the request
    callback/errback is executed (ie. when the request is downloaded)

    WARNING: Do not call request.replace() until after the deferred is called.
    """


    # zeal4u: what's the meaning of codes below?
    request_callback = request.callback
    request_errback = request.errback

    def _restore_callbacks(result):
        request.callback = request_callback
        request.errback = request_errback
        return result


    d = defer.Deferred()
    d.addBoth(_restore_callbacks)
    if request.callback:
        d.addCallbacks(request.callback, request.errback)

    request.callback, request.errback = d.callback, d.errback
    return d
```

So the point is that why it assigns 'request.callback' and 'request.errback' to local vars 'request_callback' and 'request_errback', then assigns vars back to them in next function '_restore_callbacks'?

I know this can't be useless, but what's the real meaning and how it works?
Or should I read some relevant modules to figure it out? Please give me some advice. : )

Comment: Scrapy runs on a event driven framework called Twisted. Scrapy utilizes the framework to call methods, objects or functions once something is complete. In other languages it is referred to as future, promises, delay. In Twisted it is called deferred. Here's a great introduction to Twisted [deferreds](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html). Please read it and come back to this part of code.